# chef-solo - how do you use resources from a cookbook that doesn't define any recipes?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

With chef-solo, how do you use resources from a cookbook that doesn't define any recipes? For example: https://github.com/Nordstrom/diskpart-cookbook

I've got berks downloading it into the local `cookbooks/` folder, where all my other cookbook dependencies go. I've added it to my run_list like this:

```
{
  "run_list": [ "recipe[otherstuff]", "recipe[diskpart]" ]
}
```

But when I try to import it, e.g. `include_recipe 'diskpart`, it just complains that it `could not find recipe default for cookbook diskpart`.

I'd like to use the resources defined in the repo, e.g. `diskpart_disk`.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the dependencies of the `metadata.rb` of the cookbook using the resources.

```
name 'otherstuff'
version '1.2.3'
depends 'diskpart'
```

That makes all the libraries and resources available to you without touching recipes.

Comment: I have added this to the metadata.rb, but if I remove the  "recipe[diskpart]" from the run_list, chef-solo says diskpart is no longer needed and clears it out. If I leave it in, it still complains about not being able to find the default recipe.

Comment: How are you collecting or downloading the cookbooks for use with solo?

Comment: I'm using berks to download them to a local cookbooks folder. I do this by listing them in Berkfile, then running `berks vendor cookbooks`. Most of them are from the supermarket, but the one in the example above, I explicitly reference the git repository. The file structure looks intact in the cookbooks folder.